# Get value of a button text when calling a function on addEventListener

Tags: javascript, foreach, addeventlistener

So, I'm working on this etch-a-sketch thingy for The Odin Project, however, I can't figure out how to redraw the canvas when selecting a new canvas size.

Basically, when clicking on any of the buttons that are part of the `canvasSizeButton` node the function `redrawBoard()` should run. However, I need to know the current text value of the button itself so that the `drawBoard()` function can draw the `divs` again, but I can't pass any arguments to the `redraw()` function since it breaks the whole thing and I feel using `.bind()` is not really a plausible solution to it.

TLDR; I need to make `drawBoard()` get the text value of `button` without passing any arguments nor using `.bind()`.

I'll include just the relevant part of the code.

```
function drawBoard() {
    let pixelDivider = 1;
    if (boardSize == "32x32") {
        pixelDivider = 2;
        boardSize = 32;
    } else if (boardSize == "64x64") {
        pixelDivider = 4;
        boardSize = 64;
    } else {
        pixelDivider = 1;
        boardSize = 16;
    }
    for (let j=0; j<boardSize; j++) {
        for (let i=0; i<boardSize; i++) {    
            const div = document.createElement('div');
            let pixelSize = 40 / pixelDivider;
            div.style.width = `${pixelSize}px`;
            div.style.height = `${pixelSize}px`;   
            div.classList.add('pixel')
            drawContainer.appendChild(div);
        }
    }
}

function redrawBoard () {
    let canvasSize = drawContainer.childElementCount;
    for (let i=0; i<canvasSize; i++) {
        drawContainer.removeChild(drawContainer.lastElementChild)
    }
    drawBoard();
}

const drawContainer = document.querySelector('.sketch');
drawBoard();
const canvasSizeButton = document.querySelectorAll('.canvas-size-button');


canvasSizeButton.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    redrawBoard();
}))
```

Here's the relevant html code, it's just 3 buttons with the same class and with different innerText values, which are the ones I want to get on the function:

```
<div class="canvas-size">
  <button class="canvas-size-button">16x16</button>
  <button class="canvas-size-button">32x32</button>
  <button class="canvas-size-button">64x64</button>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

I've tried using `this` but I'm not sure how it works yet. I could also do another `forEach()` inside the `drawBoard()` function but it's quite redundant to be a good approach.

Comment: Please add HTML code of this, as recommanded on this site https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: what is the  sizes in the class sketch element ?, and does `canvas-size-button` class have specific css ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're looking for something like that ?

```js
const
  e_Buttons  = document.querySelector('#Buttons')
, sz_Buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#Buttons > button')
, colorBtn   = document.querySelector('#Buttons > input[type="color"]')
, e_Board    = document.querySelector('#Board')
  ;
colorBtn.disabled = true
  ;
e_Buttons.onclick = ({target: Btn}) =>
  {
  if (!Btn.matches('button'))          return;
  if (Btn.classList.contains('activ')) return;

  sz_Buttons.forEach(bt => bt.classList.toggle('activ', bt==Btn))
  colorBtn.disabled = false;

  let
    Sizing      = Number(Btn.textContent.split('x')[0])  
  , pixelSize   = 40 / (Sizing / 16)
  , pixelsCount = Sizing**2
    ;

  while (e_Board.firstChild) 
    e_Board.removeChild(e_Board.lastChild);
  
  e_Board.style.setProperty('--pixelSize', pixelSize + 'px');
 
  for (let i = 0; i<pixelsCount; i++)
    e_Board.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  }
e_Board.onclick = ({target: pixel}) =>
  {
  if (!pixel.matches('div')) return;
  
  pixel.style.backgroundColor = colorBtn.value;
  }
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 14px;
  } 

#Board {
  --pixelSize : 40px;
  display     : block;
  width       : 640px;
  height      : 640px;
  margin      : 10px;
  background  : beige;
  overflow    : hidden;
  font-size   : 0;
  box-sizing : content-box;
  border     : 1px solid lightslategray;
  }
#Board > div {
  display    : inline-block;
  box-sizing : border-box;
  width      : var(--pixelSize);
  height     : var(--pixelSize);
  margin     : 0;
  background : lightblue;
  border     : 1px solid lightslategray;
  }
#Board > div:hover {
  border-color : white;
  cursor       : pointer;
  }
#Buttons {
  margin : 10px;
  }
#Buttons > * {
  width          : 7em;
  height         : 2.4em;
  font-weight    : bold;
  vertical-align : top;
  margin-right   : .5em;
  }
#Buttons > button.activ {
  color : red;
  }
```

```html
<div id="Buttons">
  <button>16x16</button>
  <button>32x32</button>
  <button>64x64</button>
  <input type="color" value="#e66465">
</div>

<div id="Board"></div>
```